# How can I subtract two dates in msbuild?

Tags: c#, msbuild

Since .net core does not support auto-version numbering, I am manually trying to manipulate msbuild in order to auto-generate a version number based on build date.

I have the following property group:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CurrentDate>$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString(o))</CurrentDate>
    <SecondsSinceMidnight>$(([System.DateTime]::UtcNow - [System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Date).TotalSeconds)</SecondsSinceMidnight>
    <Version>$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Year).$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Month).$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Day).$(SecondsSinceMidnight)</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

the `CurrentDate` property works great but I can't seem to get the `SecondsSinceMidnight` to work.  The error it gives is:

> The expression "([System.DateTime]::UtcNow - [System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Date).TotalSeconds" cannot be evaluated.

I suspect the issue is either with the minus sign or the extra parenthesis, but I am having trouble finding out the correct way to write this operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-` is causing problems, likely because it is not recognized as an instance method of DateTime. Instead call Subtract directly:

```
<Target Name="SubtractDates">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SecondsSinceMidnight>$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Subtract($([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Date)))</SecondsSinceMidnight>
    <Version>$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Year).$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Month).$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Day).$(SecondsSinceMidnight)</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="SecondsSinceMidnight=$(SecondsSinceMidnight)" />
  <Message Text="Version=$(Version)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, I totally forgot DateTime had a subtract method.